# Dark/murky waters

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Basically when I go underwater, the screen goes green or blue. I have tried the method to set watershadows or something to 0, but it negates the blood textures and makes the game look like a bloodless cartoon. How should I solve this? I do not want to mod my game and like I said before, setting depthoffield and radialblur removes blood which I want to retain.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use mods?

Comment: The reason is that my computer is already facing some problems, I do not want to risk making it worse, although most mods are virus-free.